# input on database structure for report system

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am currently working on a client project requires the admins to setup some daily recurring tasks for users of the system. to take temperature measurements of food

the user then fill out the task ( usually around 5 fields of data ) and if the temperatures validates the system creates a "report" on that given task. and it disappears from the users overview. the task is just not showen cause the same task is gonna pop up gain later on the week etc.

then today it stroke me that if a admin changes the control temperature values on a task it will reflect on all filled out tasks cause of my relations. and that is a no go i have to be able to change the values (they are laws regulated) and not affect the already completed reports.

What is a good approach for this ? my current one is to have the report table include all the nessaary data fields from a task and replicate em over so i can recreated the report based on the task at that give time.

or should i make the values not ediable after they are created and tell the administrators to disable the task and create a new one ? that way i allways have old task ids i can fetch values from

Hope i make sens :) ells ill be happy to explain more and make some diagrams.

Comment: What application writes to your database? You could use an SCD2 for this.

Comment: Its a standard Mssql database and i am using EF, it is more the design aproach i am after.

Comment: Yeah as I said you can use SCD 2 for your task table so when there are changes to made by admins you would insert a new row with a current start date. Heres an example from Jamie - http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/11/28/debunking-kimball-effective-dates.aspx